# Efficient polygon clip between z values

Tags: php, algorithm, polygon, clipping

I am currently using Sutherland-Hodgeman algorithm for polygon clipping which works perfectly for case 2 (see image below). Problem is when there are more solutions (see case 1).

Performance also seems to be a problem as I dont need to use any complex polygons for clipping. I am using a rectangle with let's say X from -1000 to 1000 to simulate clipping between Z values.

I am curious if there are any clipping algorithms that can deal with multiple solutions and are of simplier complexity then Sutherland-Hodgeman. I just need to clip between certain Z values fast.

[image: Polygon clipping]

Thanks for any ideas.

PS: language is PHP, currently using modified algorithm from here https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sutherland-Hodgman_polygon_clipping#PHP